# SQL ACCESS - select max(date) and corresponding value

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, select, max

How can I get the corresponding value of MAX(date).
Access it returns me an error when I select directly the column with the specified value.

For example, I want to be shown only the line from the image.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What's the expected result if there are two rows with the same max date?

Answer (score 4):

Use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select top 1 *
from t
order by date desc;
```

EDIT:

If you want the last date per code, then use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.code = t.code);
```

Comment: thank you, but this returns me only the transactions from the last date of the entire database.
I need to have the last date per Code.

Answer (score 1):

`select * from tblName where DocumentDate in (select max(DocumentDate ) from tblName)`

Please use this

Answer (score 1):

If you need last date per code then try this one

```
SELECT Code, MAX(DocumentDate)
FROM table
GROUP BY Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You mast creat the join query. For example find `MAX(DocumentDate)`:

```
SELECT DocumentNumber, Code, SoldPuncte, DocumentDate   
from yourTable a inner join 
          (SELECT DocumentNumber, Code, SoldPuncte, MAX(DocumentDate) as 
          DocumentDate 
          from yourTable group by DocumentNumber) b 
on a.DocumentNumber=b.DocumentNumber and a.DocumentDate = b.DocumentDate
```